# Quicksort an array of personne by their number

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am trying to use quicksort to sort the pers array according to the people's number. I have an output but the array is not sorted correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>   
#include <string>
#include <fstream>   
using namespace std;


class Personne
{
    private :
        char sexe ;
        float taille, poids ;
        int numero;
    
    public :
        Personne(char sexe, int numero, float taille, float poids); 

        Personne()      
        {
        
        }  
     
        int getNumero();
    
        void afficher()
        {
            cout << setw(6) << sexe 
                 << setw(10) << numero
                 << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << taille
                 << setw(12) << setprecision(1) << poids << endl;
        }
};


int Personne::getNumero()
{
    return numero;
}


Personne::Personne(char sexe, int numero, float taille, float poids)
{
    this->sexe = sexe;
    this->numero = numero;
    this->taille = taille;
    this->poids = poids;            
}  


void lireRemplir(const char nomALire[], Personne pers[], int &n)
{   
    const float PIED_EN_METRE = 0.3048, LIVRE_EN_KG = 0.454;
    int numero, nbPieds, nbPouces, nbLivres;
    float taille, poids;
    char sexe;
          
    ifstream aLire(nomALire, ios::in);      // localiser et ouvrir pour la lecture
        n = 0;
                
        while(aLire >> sexe >> numero >> nbPieds >> nbPouces >> nbLivres)                  
        {
            taille = (nbPieds + nbPouces /12.0) * PIED_EN_METRE;
            poids  = nbLivres * LIVRE_EN_KG ;                                
            pers[n++] = Personne(sexe, numero, taille, poids);               
        }
        
        aLire.close();   
}


void afficher(Personne tab[], int nbElement, string message = "")
{
    cout << "TABLEAU DES PERSONNES " << message << " :"<< endl;
    cout << "Indice   Sexe   Numero   Taille(m)   Poids(kg)" << endl;
        
    for(int i = 0; i < nbElement; i++)
        { 
            cout << setw(3) << i << ") ";
            tab[i].afficher();
        }
        
    cout << endl;
}


void permuter(Personne &a, Personne &b)
{
    Personne temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}


int partitionner(Personne tab[], int debut, int fin)
{
    int d = debut, f = fin;
    int valPivot = tab[d].getNumero();

    while(d <= f)
        {   
            while(d <= f && tab[d].getNumero() <= valPivot)
                d++;
            
            while(tab[f].getNumero() > valPivot) 
                f--;

            if(d < f)
                permuter(tab[d], tab[f]);
        }

    permuter(tab[f], tab[d]);
    
    return f;
}


void quickSort(Personne tab[], int debut, int fin)
{
    if (fin > debut)
    {
        int indPivot = partitionner(tab, debut, fin);
        quickSort(tab, debut, indPivot-1);
        quickSort(tab, indPivot+1, fin);
    }
}     


    
int main() 
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    
    const int MAX_PERS = 25 ;
    Personne pers[MAX_PERS];
    int nbPers;
 
    lireRemplir("imp_e20.txt", pers, nbPers);
    
    afficher(pers, nbPers);
    
    quickSort(pers, 0, nbPers-1);
    
    afficher(pers, nbPers, "APRES LE TRI SELON NUMERO");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: I am french Canadian so some words in my code are in french, sorry.

Comment: Since this is C++ you should to use something like `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: Are you doing an exercise to write your own sorting function, or are you just trying to get them sorted?

Comment: If you want your code to be understandable by others, you should stick with half-open ranges: (0,4) includes 0 but excludes 4. It makes everything simpler. If this was your intent, then, it seems: `quickSort(tab, debut, indPivot-1); quickSort(tab, indPivot+1, fin);` is wrong as it leaves two empty spots.

Comment: *I am not a number! I am a free man!*. Your partition implementation doesn't look like any of the common partition implementations. It's sort of half Lomuto and half Hoare. I'd base the implementation on one of the two. There's good pseudocode at the [quicksort wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)